# My gauss filter is too slow

Tags: python, scipy

I am making a simple gauss blur, and since I could not make scipy's convolve work, I made my own:

```
def Convolve(matr_, ker_):
    output = matr_.astype(np.float64)
    for x in range(len(matr_)):
        for y in range(len(matr_[x])):
            sum = 0
            count = 0
            width = int(len(ker_)/2)
            for x_c in range(len(ker_)):
                for y_c in range(len(ker_)):
                    x_index = x - x_c + width
                    y_index = y - y_c + width
                    if (x_index >= 0) and (x_index < len(matr_)) and (y_index >= 0) and (y_index < len(matr_[x])):
                        sum += ker_[x_c][y_c] * matr_[x_index][y_index]
                        count += ker_[x_c][y_c]
                    else:
                        #print("{0} -> {1}, {2} -> {3}".format(x, x_index, y, y_index))
                        pass
            output[x][y] = sum/count
    return output.astype(matr_.dtype)
```

I also normalize pixels right here, so they would still always fit `matr_`'s type. But it works really slow, it takes up something like 20 seconds to work with a 1440x900 image. How can this be made to work faster?

Comment: You could use `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I want to try writing my own.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use loops in Python if you can avoid it. Use Numpy or Pandas and work on vectors.

If you *have* to use loops (which doesn't seem to be the case in your example), use the Numba package.

Comment: How would you put convolution in terms of vectors?